# How can I format a textbox number to curreny with 2 decimal places?

Tags: winui-3, winui

How can I format the text of a textblock as currency with two decimal places?

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Premium, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I want to configure something like DisplayFormat="c2" and the result should be for instance 10,23$
Something that detects the configured global/thread currency.

I did not find a property under https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox?view=winrt-22621

or a binding feature that allows that. Not sure if the numberbox would be appropriate. I need it only readable as info for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [function binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings), like this:

```
<Window xmlns:sys="using:System" ...>
...
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Format('{0:C2}', ViewModel.Premium)}" />
...
</Window>
```

PS: can't be TwoWay in the case since it's now a computed value